# Flutter : How can i delete a Document from firebase without mentioning it's ID

Tags: firebase, flutter, collections

How can i delete a Document from firebase without mentioning it's ID.
Is it possible to delete the first document of the collection.
Can someone help me with the code?

```
IconButton(
        
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
        onPressed:()async{ 
         await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('eNotification').doc().delete();
         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Notification Deleted',toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        textColor: Colors.white,fontSize: 16.0);
        } ,
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to write to or delete a document you must know its full path, including its ID. There is no way to delete a document without knowing its ID.

This typically means you must store the ID for each document you display in your app, so that you can then pass that ID to Firestore when needed.